# Coordinates of mesh generated by Mathematica-FEM

Tags: plotting, graphics, finite-element-method, mesh, coordinate

MeshCoordinates function yields more nodal coordinates than expected. Can I extract the coordinates of vertices only. Here is an example of a square region with a course mesh to explain the problem. I would like the code get me the following coordinates:{{0., 0.}, {0., 0.5}, {0., 1.}, {0.5, 0.}, {0.5, 0.5}, {0.5, 1.}, {1.,0.}, {1., 0.5}, {1., 1.}}.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
d = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[d2, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.5];
mesh["Wireframe"]
MeshCoordinates[mesh2][[1, 1]]
```

Comment: `d2,mesh2` should be `d,mesh`in your code I think. `mesh = ToElementMesh[d, MaxCellMeasure -> 1 ];` give the coordinates you wish to get.

Answer (score 1):

The function `MeshCoordinates` works for `MeshRegion`. `ToElementMesh`, however, returns an `ElementMesh`. For an `ElementMesh` you can extract the coordinates in the following manner:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
d = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[d2, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.5];
mesh["Wireframe"]
mesh["Coordinates"]
```

If you want a first order mesh use:

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[d2, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.5,"MeshOrder"->1];
```

Also, I encourage you to look at the documentation of `ToElementMesh` and `ElementMesh` for more information.

Comment: V. clear. Many thanks.